# Example sentences that can be insulting

Tags: discussion

This is in reference to [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93114/can-supposed-to-be-used-to-mean-considered-to) post.

One of the example sentences is *Asians are not supposed to be good ball players.*

I realize that the OP is just trying to provide examples to illustrate his question, but I also think it is possible to find examples that do not touch on the sensitive subject of racism.

I also realize that some people argue that the world is becoming very PC, maybe too PC. But given the amount of controversy recently surrounding Asian basketball player, [Jeremy Lin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeremy_Lin#Racial_issues), I think the community should at least discuss it.

Does the community moderate/edit such posts? Thoughts?

Comment: We had some discussion about this a couple years ago, but I can't find it for the life of me. I hope it hasn't been deleted.

Comment: I wasn't around a couple of years ago, so I don't know what conclusions the community reached. My personal opinion is that, if anyone feels insulted because of a sentence like the one mentioned, that person is over-sensitive. Nothing good can come of such an attitude, looking for malice where supposedly there was none.

Comment: related to [Are minor jokes in answers and questions OK when they are slightly discriminating against certain groups?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/904/19644)

Answer (score 3):

The question is specifically asking about the phrase *supposed to*, and asking about its usage in the negative to express a stereotype.  That's a valid language question.

As a member of the community, you're always welcome to come up with an equally good example that you find less offensive, and make an edit. Of course, that might be quite a challenge in the context of a stereotype. I thought of a few examples, but, in this particular case, the nature of the phrasal usage is bound to be off-putting for someone:

> New Yorkers are not supposed to be considerate.
>   Women are not supposed to be good drivers.
>   Rich people are not supposed to be good tippers.
>   Short people are not supposed to be good ball players.

By the way, I have very nice friends who hail from New York, my wife is a competent and safe driver, and I don't ascribe to the stereotype that well-off people never leave generous tips.  All that, plus [Spud Webb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spud_Webb).

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that it *is* possible to find an example sentence to which somebody somewhere won't object, and I certainly don't believe it desirable to censor free discussion for such a trivial reason as this.  If a post said "Asians are not good ball players" this question would be worth asking (though my personal answer would still be "Don't censor it, assuming the point's relevant"): if a post said "Asians are not supposed to be good ball players" then it would be viciously illiberal to try and prevent somebody asserting a (perhaps unwelcome) fact about Western society: but to object even to a mention of the sentence, without any indication of the poster's actual views, borders on the Stalinist.